# Align input field with button in smaller screen go out of bound

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, materialize

I'm trying to aligne an input field with a button at the bottom of a tchat.

Here is the result on normal screen size +15"

[image]

and here is the result on -15"

[image]

Html :

```
 <div class="col footer">
  <div class="divider"></div>
  <div class="row footer-input input-container form-group">
    <div class="input-field inline col s10 m10">
      <input #messageInput type="text">
      <label for="message">Tapez votre message</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col button-col s2 m2">
      <a class="waves-effect btn blue"">
        <i class="material-icons">send</i></a>
      <app-loading-panel [visible]="isSending"></app-loading-panel>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Css :

```
div.divider {
  margin-top: 2px;
}

div.footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

div.input-container {
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

input[type=text]:focus:not([readonly]) {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #2196F3;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 #2196F3;
}

input[type=text]:focus:not([readonly]) + label {
  color: #2196F3;
}

div.footer-input {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

div.button-col {
  height: 100%;
}
```

I'm not good with css, how can I have the input take all the place it can, the button be at the right and centered vertically and nothing going out of bound ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this might help you from a basic perspective:

1. Have a container that's a flex box
2. Assign a flex-grow of 1 to the input
3. This will ensure the input takes up most of the space whilst the button remains on the right.

```css
.container {
  width: auto;
  background: #ebebeb;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
.container input {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Some Stuff"/>
  <button> Button </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Ok my bad it works I forgot something :) only two things. How can I align the button vertically ? and when the field is not selected a full vertical scroll bar apear on the entire page